# Can't get variables

Tags: 7, debugging

I'm trying to get variables to use them in my module but I can' get them.

I try `print_r($variables)` and get

```
"Undefined variable: variables in include_once().."
```

The same happens if I try to get $page, $html, $node, etc.

I tried to use `dpm()` and gets a blank content.

Anyone seen anything like this? I don't understand.

Comment: where exactly you are trying to access variables? is it a template file or a specific hook?

Answer (score 4):

`$variables` isn't a global variable accessible to any module. Most of the variable names you've mentioned are a part of (or naming convention in) D7's templating engine. For example:

- `$variables` is common parameter name for most of template preprocessing functions (e.g. [`template_preprocess_node()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7)). In the context of the preprocessing function, it contains a keyed array of variables that will be injected into the template (e.g. `$variables['node']` will be `$node` in **[node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7)**)
- `$page` is the variable named used in **[page.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7)** that contains Drupal block region data.

If you're curious what variables are globally accessible to Drupal 7 modules see [this page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/globals/7). Any these variables can be accessed by using the `global` keyword followed by the variable name (e.g. `global $user` to access the current user object in a module function).